# ADO.NET,MVC 5,N-Tier Connecting to Database and pulling all results from a table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I'm currently stuck, and I can't seem to find a way out (I can't use automapper), but I'm supposed to grab information from a database, we're mixing N-Tier with, MVC for the layout, we're using SQL Server 2012, and Visual Studio 2015. I am supposed to connect to the database, and list all the customers from the table "Customers", We're using the northwnd database, and we have to use stored procedures for SQL functionality. I'm desperate at this point, I'm behind on MVC, ADO.NET, SQL Commands(C#), and its killing me even resources that'd help me learn are highly valued. With that being said could someone give me an example I'll list what I've got below. Thank you all for your help.
**Business Logic Layer**

```
  public class BusinessLogic
{
    static DataAccess _DataAccess = new DataAccess();
    public List<BLLBO> ListCustomers()
    {
        List<BLLBO> to = new List<BLLBO>();
        List<DALDO> from = _DataAccess.ViewAllUsers();
        foreach (DALDO lItem in from)
        {
            BLLBO lItemBO = BLL_MAP.MapToPO(lItem);

        }
        return to;
    }
}
```

**Data Access Layer MAP**

```
     public static DALDO TableToCustomers (DataRow iSource)
    {
        DALDO oResult = new DALDO();
        oResult.CustomerID = iSource["CustomerID"].ToString();
        oResult.CompanyName = iSource["CompanyName"].ToString();
        oResult.ContactName = iSource["ContactName"].ToString();
        oResult.ContactTitle = iSource["ContactTitle"].ToString();
        oResult.Address = iSource["Address"].ToString();
        oResult.City = iSource["City"].ToString();
        oResult.Region = iSource["Region"].ToString();
        oResult.PostalCode = iSource["PostalCode"].ToString();
        oResult.Country = iSource["Country"].ToString();
        oResult.Phone = iSource["Phone"].ToString();
        oResult.Fax = iSource["Fax"].ToString();
        return oResult;
    }
    public static List<DALDO> TableToListOFCustomers(DataTable iSource)
    {
        List<DALDO> oResult = new List<DALDO>();
        if (iSource != null && iSource.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow iRow in iSource.Rows)
            {
                DALDO iMappedItem = TableToCustomers(iRow);
                oResult.Add(iMappedItem);
            }
        }
        return oResult;
    }
```

**DataAccess Layer**

```
        public static string _ConnectionString = @"Server=ADMIN2-PC\MYINSTANCE;Database=NORTHWND;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    public List<DALDO> ViewAllUsers()
    {
        List<DALDO> lDaldo = new List<DALDO>();
        DataTable oResult = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection iConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand iCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT_CUSTOMERS", iConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                iConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter iAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(iCommand))
                {
                    iAdapter.Fill(oResult);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw;

            }
            finally
            {
                iConnection.Close();
            }
            lDaldo = DAL_MAP.TableToListOFCustomers(oResult);
        }
        return lDaldo;
    }
```

**Objects(All the same there's three, Presentiation, Logic, and Data)**

```
        public static string _ConnectionString = @"Server=ADMIN2-PC\MYINSTANCE;Database=NORTHWND;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    public List<DALDO> ViewAllUsers()
    {
        List<DALDO> lDaldo = new List<DALDO>();
        DataTable oResult = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection iConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand iCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT_CUSTOMERS", iConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                iConnection.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter iAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(iCommand))
                {
                    iAdapter.Fill(oResult);
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw;

            }
            finally
            {
                iConnection.Close();
            }
            lDaldo = DAL_MAP.TableToListOFCustomers(oResult);
        }
        return lDaldo;
    }
```

**Standard Map(Two of these for logic, and presentation)**

```
            public static DALDO MapToPO(BLLBO iMapped)
    {
        DALDO oResult = new DALDO();
        oResult.CustomerID = iMapped.CustomerID;
        oResult.CompanyName = iMapped.CompanyName;
        oResult.ContactName = iMapped.ContactName;
        oResult.ContactTitle = iMapped.ContactTitle;
        oResult.Address = iMapped.Address;
        oResult.City = iMapped.City;
        oResult.Region = iMapped.Region;
        oResult.PostalCode = iMapped.PostalCode;
        oResult.Country = iMapped.Country;
        oResult.Phone = iMapped.Phone;
        oResult.Fax = iMapped.Fax;

        return oResult;
    }
```

The presentation layer is pretty much an MVC controllers, and view. We use empty templates.

Comment: do you really need to provide all this codes? narrow down your question and keep it short.

Comment: this is a site for getting help resolving specific technical questions, not for you to make requests for people to do your work for you because "you are behind" and don't understand your own tools.

Comment: For future "People" who find this. To connect N-Tier MVC to your database, the only difference is your map will swap to SQL statements in the Data Access layer. Yoour controller should call a series of methods that will map down to your business logic layer, and then to your data access layer where the SQL commands will be called from a series of methods, create class libraries to map you'll need three of them. Public,Logic, and Data.